# Understanding a proof that a collection of complex numbers on one side of a line through $0$ must have a non-zero sum

Tags: geometry, complex-numbers

I'm asked to prove that if $z_1$, $\ldots$, $z_k$ lie on one side of a straight line through $0$, then $z_1+\cdots+z_k \neq 0$.

In the proof, we let $\theta$ be the angle between the line and the real axis, and let  $w = \cos\theta + i\sin\theta$. Then $z_1w^{-1}$, $\ldots$, $z_kw^{-1}$ all lie on one side of the real axis, so the same is true for $z_1w^{-1}+\cdots+z_kw^{-1} = (z_1+\cdots+z_k)w^{-1}$, which shows that $z_1+\cdots+z_k$ lies on the corresponding side of the original line.

> But why is it the case that if we divide the various $z_i$s of the original sequence by $w$ then they all get sorted on one side of the real axis? I get that the points all rotate clockwise by $\theta$, but why?

Thank you all in advance.

Simon.

Edit: I think I've answered it myself; see below.

Comment: Multiplying by $w^{-1}$ rotates everything clockwise by $\theta$, so it map the line through $0$ and $w$ to the real axis.

Comment: "Multiplying by $w^{-1}$ rotates everything clockwise by θ" Sure, but why?

Comment: @Simone Because multiplying be $e^{i\theta}$ in the complex plane is equivalent to a (counter-clockwise) rotation of angle $\theta$ and center $O$. Why, you may still ask? Well, just write the complex product and compare to the rotation in $\Bbb R^2$. See also [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_(mathematics)#Two_dimensions).

Comment: "I get that the points all rotate clockwise by theta, but why?"  I'm having trouble parsing this.  Do you mean that you accept that the statement is true, but don't know why it's true?  (The reason I ask is that usually, "get" in this context means "understand," not simply "accept.")

Comment: Note that there's nothing special about the complex plane here - it is just a dimension $2$ vector space.  In general it's true that if $v_1, \ldots, v_k \in \mathbb{R}^n$ are all to one side of a hyperplane $H$ then the sum will also be on that side (and in particular, will not be $0$.)

Comment: @BrianTung I understand that with this proof we're trying to rotate the points by $\theta$ in order to reduce the general case to the particular where the straight line through $0$ is the real axis. But analytically: why does this happen?

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut Thanks for the link. I get that going through the multiplication we get new coordinates $x'$ and $y'$ for the new (rotated) complex number $z'$. For the clockwise rotation necessary for the theorem I've calculated the new point $z''$ to be:
$$zw^{-1}=\frac{x+iy}{\cos\theta+i\sin\theta}=\frac{x(\cos\theta-i\sin\theta)}{\cos^2\theta+\sin^2\theta}+\frac{iy(\cos\theta-i\sin\theta}{\cos^2\theta+\sin^2\theta}=(x\cos\theta+y\sin\theta)-i(x\sin\theta-y\cos\theta)$$

right?
But why are the resulting z' and z'' rotations of z?

Comment: @Simone Are you comfortable with the equation $e^{i\theta}=\cos\theta + i \sin \theta$? Or with rotation matrices in $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Comment: I added an answer to my own question; I think it's cogent but I'm not 100% sure. What do you guys think of it?

Comment: Geometrically, if $z_1$ and $z_2$ are on the same side of a line through the origin, the diagonal of the parallelogram built on $z_1$ and $z_2$ is on the same side.

Comment: @Maxim I get it, but that wasn't the question. 
Anyway, I think I've answered it already;go check my last answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it!

let $$z=|z|(\cos(\theta+|r|)+i\sin(\theta+|r|))$$

so $$zw^{-1}=\frac{|z|(\cos(\theta+|r|)+i\sin(\theta+|r|))}{\cos\theta+i\sin\theta}=|z|\frac{\cos\theta\cos|r|-\sin\theta\sin|r|+i\sin\theta\cos|r|+i\cos\theta\sin|r|}{\cos\theta+i\sin\theta}=|z|\frac{\cos\theta\cos|r|+i^2\sin\theta\sin|r|+i\sin\theta\cos|r|+i\cos\theta\sin|r|}{\cos\theta+i\sin\theta}=|z|\frac{(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta)(\cos|r|+i\sin|r|)}{\cos\theta+i\sin\theta}=|z|(\cos|r|+i\sin|r|)$$

which is the point $z''$ of lenght $|z|$ with an angle of $|r|$ radians.

I feel like this answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

It is not difficult to prove the case $k=2$, than use induction.

---

Or, following your way:

if all $z_i$ lie on the same side of the line $z=\rho e^{i\theta}$
we have
$$z_i=\rho_ie^{i(\theta +\alpha_i)}$$
 with $0<\alpha_i<\pi$ or $-\pi<\alpha_i<0$.

So we have:

$z_i e^{-i\theta}=\rho_ie^{i(\theta +\alpha_i)}e^{-i\theta}=\rho_ie^{i \alpha_i}$

which, due to the  limits for $\alpha_i$, are all on the same side of the real axis.

Comment: I don't feel like this answers the question; I have already outlined the proof.

Answer (score 0):

I might have convinced myself; but should I be convinced?

I suspect that it's easier for me to think of this points using polar coordinates:
we started with:
$$x+iy=z=|z|(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta)$$
so
$$x=|z|\cos\theta$$and$$y=|z|\sin\theta$$
in a comment below my initial question I've found that the $\theta$ clockwise rotation of $z$ obtained by $zw^{-1}$ as above is given in terms of $x$ and $y$ by the formula:
$$z''=(x\cos\theta+y\sin\theta)-i(x\sin\theta-y\cos\theta)$$
let $x\gt0$ and we can accept $\theta=arctan (y/x)$, and thus we can substitute as such:

$${x\over \sqrt{y^2+x^2\over x^2}}+{y^2\over x\sqrt{y^2+x^2\over x^2}}-{iyx\over x\sqrt{y^2+x^2\over x^2}}+{iy\over \sqrt{y^2+x^2\over x^2}}={x^2\over\sqrt{y^2+x^2}}+{y^2 \over\sqrt{y^2+x^2}}={x^2\over |z|}+{y^2\over |z|}= \frac 1{|z|}(x^2+y^2)=\frac 1{|z|}{|z|}^2\cos^2\theta+\frac 1{|z|}{|z|}^2\sin^2\theta=|z|(\cos^2\theta+\sin^2\theta)=|z|=|z|(\cos0+i\sin0)$$
which is the point $z''$ with the same modulus $|z|$ of $z$ but laid on the real axis.

makes sense?

Comment: Obviously you can substitute for $x$ and $y$ in $z''$ right away without the substitution of $\theta$, silly me.